# How to embed Processing with Minim into html?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, minim

I'm trying to embed the Processing that contains Minim into html. 
It reads the code but nothing showed up.

Thank you !

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A LOAD OF WAFFLE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="minim.js"></script>
</head>
    <style>
        .html {
            background-color: smokewhite;
        }
    </style>

<body>
<!--<script>
    </script> -->
<script src="BorisPiano.pde"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the path given to scripts? try src="./processing.js"

Comment: Where are you getting `minim.js`? Please consult your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for any errors and include them in your post.